# Permission denied on creating repository lock file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to publish my repository and below is the feedback i get.
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Windows/System32/attc/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Please, i tried to signed out signed in again with my credentials through github but same problem.

Comment: The the problem does not rely on git permissions. The problem is git has no write permission in c:/Windows/System32/attc/.git. Why would you store your repo in System32?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.